# Why is the Flash Video Player not showing in Firefox?

Tags: flash, youtube, swfobject

I am trying to implement a Flash YouTube video player on [this page](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/inside1.html). I am using swfobject.

Here is the code:

```
        <!-- begin youTube player -->
        <div id="flashArea" class="flashArea" style="height:376;">
            <p>This content requires the Adobe Flash Player.<br />
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a><br />
            <a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflash/">Get Flash</a></p>
        </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mainswf = new SWFObject("youtube_player_standalone.swf", "main", "600", "250", "9", "#000000");
    mainswf.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    mainswf.addParam("wmode", "window");
    mainswf.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    mainswf.addVariable("youtube_id", "_EC2tmFVNNE");
    mainswf.addVariable("title", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows");
    mainswf.addVariable("controls_always_on", "false");
    mainswf.addVariable("controls_fade_out_time", "5");
    mainswf.addVariable("volume_cookie_on", "true");
    mainswf.write("flashArea");
  </script>
  <!-- end flash player -->
```

The only problem is that the player does not show up. Scroll down the page and right below Secondary Headline there is a large white space - this is where the player is.

I have tried it in isolation [here](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/youTubePlayer/) and it works fine, but something is messing it up on the destination page.

I would appreciate any assistance to sort this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct embedding format for Firefox, that is the only browser that didn't show the video. Chrome, IE, and Safari all displayed it correctly.

It might be that your height is set to `376` instead of `376px`

On your `tip_style.css` file on line 32 you have `#main{padding-bottom:250px}` try removing that.

Comment: Hi John, I moved the styling up to the header and added px to the height a border just to see if it responded. The border shows but the player still does not. I am not sure what else might make the difference for firefox. Thanks.

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you very much for the help.